# Is this correct: "Why does the fact that John has a girlfriend bothers me so much?"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, present-tense

'Why does the fact that John has a girlfriend bothers me so much?'

Is this grammatically correct? I mean the tenses. 'Does' and 'bothers' sound a little awkward to me.

Comment: How about:  'So, John has a girlfriend..."
                    -description (two lines)-
                    'Why does it bother me so much?'

Answer (score 1):

It sounds a lot awkward to me.  You can't have **does** followed by a verb with the **-s** suffix.

You need **does...bother.**

Comment: Since the sentence is too awkward, how about: 'So, John has a girlfriend...' -from a new line; description (two lines)- 'Why does it bother me so much?'

Comment: I don't see the corrected sentence as awkward.  But if you want to break it up, that's certainly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's ungrammatical: 'Why does the fact that John has a girlfriend bothers me so much?'.  The problem is that "bothers" agrees in number with the subject "the fact ...", but in this position, "bother" is not finite, and only finite verbs (those inflected for tense) agree.

In a corresponding statement, "bother" can be finite: "The fact bothers me."  Then, it agrees with its singular subject, "the fact".  But in this question, instead of "bothers", we have "does bother", where the finite verb of the clause has become "does", which displays singular agreement with its singular subject "the fact":
"The fact does bother me."  You couldn't say *"The fact does bothers me", because a clause cannot have two finite verbs.  Once "bothers" is changed to "does bother", the auxiliary "does" is the one finite verb of the clause, and "bother" has become non-finite.  Now, it can no longer agree.

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion...no 's' in the bothers will make it sound good.

Why does the fact that John has a girlfriend bother me so much?'

Answer (score -4):

if you really like to use 'bothers' how about 
It bothers me so much, the fact that John has a girlfriend.

Comment: It needs to stay a question though.

Comment: With that constraint....bother is ideal.

Comment: Or "why does it bother me so much that John has a girlfriend?"